# How can I structure my folders to test my code:

Tags: python, pytest

I'm working on a project and would like to write some unit tests for my code.  Here is a minimal example of my project structure

```
myproject
└── scripts
    ├── tests
    │   └── test_func.py
    └── tools
        ├── __init__.py
        └── func.py
```

`func.py` contains

```
def f(x):
    return 0
```

and `test_func.py` contains

```
import pytest 
from ..tools import f

def test_f():

    assert f(1)==0
```

When I try to run my tests with pytest `pytest scripts/tests/test_func.py`, I get the following error `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`.

Clearly, there is a problem with the structure of my project.  [There is a solution here which involves adding something to my path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3) but I'd rather not do that if there is a way I can just structure my project to avoid this instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add (empty) `__init__.py` files to the directories `scripts/` and `scripts/tests/`. These files provide the scaffolding that lets `import` find modules, especially when using relative imports.

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat directories containing the file as packages.

From https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html