# How do I structure my python project such that my test files can import the packages in the root folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I would like to integrate **pytest** into my workflow. I made a following folder structure:

```
myproject
├── venv
└── src
    ├── __init__.py 
    ├── foo
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── bar.py
    └── tests
        ├── __init__.py
        └── test_bar.py
```

I would like to be able to import the namespace from the `foo` package so that I can write test scripts in the `tests` folder. Whenever I try to run `pytest`, or `pytest --import-mode append` I always get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'
```

I found this similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64623668/how-can-i-structure-my-folders-to-test-my-code) but adding the `__init__.py` files to the `tests` and the `src` folder does not solve the issue.

Does this have to do with the PYTHONPATH system variable? This folder structure works perfectly if I run the `__main__.py` from the `src` folder, but fails when I want to use `pytest`. Is there a way to do this without having to mess with PYTHONPATH or are there automated ways to edit the system variable?

Comment: What is the import statement that you are using for fetching the files from ```foo``` folder?

Comment: I tried two options:


1) Nothing in the foo `__init__.py` file and using `import foo`


2) Importing the functions I need within `__init__.py` and using `from foo import baz`


Neither of these work.

Comment: Did you try this approach - 
Add a ```__init__.py``` file under the ```tests``` folder alone then try to use ```from foo import *``` in your ```test_bar.py``` file

Comment: In the `foo` folder I have a file called `bar.py` and within that I have a function called `baz`. I added `from foo import *` to the `test_bar.py` file and this works and I can call `baz()` without issue.

Comment: Actually all types of `import` commands seem to work now that I deleted the `__init__.py` from the `src` folder.

Comment: Yes you need to keep the ```__init__.py``` file only under the ```test``` folder. Not anywhere else

Comment: By adding an `__init__.py` into `src` directory, you have effectively made `src` a package, so the import path of the `bar` module is now `src.foo.bar`. This is not what the `src` layout is used for. The `src` dir is there to ensure you don't import code from your repository, instead testing how the installed package behaves. You don't probably need to use the `src` layout in the first place.

Comment: I wanted to add the `src` folder because the project I started to work on requires a bunch assets, data folders etc, but it's actually not relevant to the question. But now I understand the problem thanks!